# How to solve geofence mock_location error?

Tags: android, google-maps, geofencing, android-geofence, android-googleapiclient

so im running this sample app i got on github which deals with google maps and geo fences: https://github.com/androidfu/GeofenceExample

And when I run the code I get this error :  `Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: com.androidfu.example.geofences from uid 10170 not allowed to perform MOCK_LOCATION`

Here is the code for the class followed by the stack trace. Hope you guys can give me some insight. Also i have mock location in manifest. The error is coming from the onResume() method.

```
 public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener, ResultCallback<Status> {

        public static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

        private static final long LOCATION_ITERATION_PAUSE_TIME = 1000;
        private static final int NUMBER_OF_LOCATION_ITERATIONS = 10;

        private GoogleMap googleMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
        private MyPlaces happyPlace;
        private MyPlaces home;
        private List<Geofence> myFences = new ArrayList<>();
        private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
        private PendingIntent geofencePendingIntent;
        private UpdateLocationRunnable updateLocationRunnable;
        private LocationManager locationManager;
        private int marker = 0;
        private Location lastLocation;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

            ImageButton happyPlaceBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib_happy_place);
            happyPlaceBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

            ImageButton homeBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib_home);
            homeBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

            ImageButton resetBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib_reset);
            resetBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

            setUpMapIfNeeded();
        }

        /**
         * Called when a view has been clicked.
         *
         * @param v The view that was clicked.
         */
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            MyPlaces place;
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.ib_happy_place:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "You Clicked Happy Place", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    place = happyPlace;
                    moveToLocation(place);
                    break;
                case R.id.ib_home:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "You Clicked Home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    place = home;
                    moveToLocation(place);
                    break;
                case R.id.ib_reset:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Resetting Our Map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (updateLocationRunnable != null) {
                        updateLocationRunnable.interrupt();
                    }
                    googleApiClient.disconnect();
                    googleMap.clear();
                    myFences.clear();
                    setUpMap();
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

            setUpMapIfNeeded();

            this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

            Log.i(TAG, "Setup MOCK Location Providers");
            locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            Log.i(TAG, "GPS Provider");
            locationManager.addTestProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, Criteria.POWER_HIGH, Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            locationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, true);

            Log.i(TAG, "Network Provider");
            locationManager.addTestProvider(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, true, false, true, false, false, false, false, Criteria.POWER_MEDIUM, Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            locationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            this.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

            // Interrupt our runnable if we're going into the background or exiting
            if (updateLocationRunnable != null) {
                updateLocationRunnable.interrupt();
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "Cleanup Our Fields");
            locationManager.removeTestProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            locationManager.removeTestProvider(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            locationManager = null;
            updateLocationRunnable = null;

            super.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            googleApiClient.disconnect();
            super.onStop();
        }

        /**
         * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
         * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
         * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #googleMap} is not null.
         * <p/>
         * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
         * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
         * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
         * <p/>
         * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
         * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
         * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
         * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
         * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
         */
        private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
            // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
            if (googleMap == null) {
                // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
                googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
                // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
                if (googleMap != null) {
                    setUpMap();
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera.
         * <p/>
         * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #googleMap} is not null.
         */
        private void setUpMap() {
            googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);

            // PRES 1
            /*
                1. Create a "Place" that will become a Geofence
                2. Add a place marker on our Map
                3. Add our place to our list of Geofences
                4. Repeat for each place
             */

            // Add a place with a Geofence
            happyPlace = new MyPlaces("Pier @ Folly Beach", "This is my Happy Place!", new LatLng(32.652411, -79.938063), 10000, 10, R.drawable.ic_palm_tree);
            addPlaceMarker(happyPlace);
            addFence(happyPlace);

            // Add a place with a Geofence
            // Work 39.3336585, -84.3146718
            // Home 39.2697455, -84.269921
            home = new MyPlaces("Home", "This is where I live.", new LatLng(39.3336585, -84.3146718), 10000, 10, R.drawable.ic_home);
            addPlaceMarker(home);
            addFence(home);

            // Add a place w/o a Geofence
            MyPlaces charleston = new MyPlaces("Charleston, SC", "This is where I want to live!", new LatLng(32.8210454, -79.9704779), 0, 10, R.drawable.ic_heart);
            addPlaceMarker(charleston);
            addFence(charleston);

            /*
                After all your places have been created and markers added you can monitor your fences.
             */
            monitorFences(myFences);

            googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

                    if (updateLocationRunnable != null && updateLocationRunnable.isAlive() && !updateLocationRunnable.isInterrupted()) {
                        updateLocationRunnable.interrupt();
                    }
                    updateLocationRunnable = new UpdateLocationRunnable(locationManager, latLng);
                    updateLocationRunnable.start();

                    MyPlaces touchedPlace = new MyPlaces(String.format("Marker %1$d", ++marker), "", latLng, 65, 12, 0);
                    addPlaceMarker(touchedPlace);
                }
            });
        }

        /**
         * Add a map marker at the place specified.
         *
         * @param place the place to take action on
         */
        private void addPlaceMarker(MyPlaces place) {
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(place.getCoordinates())
                    .title(place.getTitle());
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(place.getSnippet())) {
                markerOptions.snippet(place.getSnippet());
            }
            if (place.getIconResourceId() > 0) {
                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(place.getIconResourceId()));
            }
            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            drawGeofenceAroundTarget(place);
        }

        /**
         * If our place has a fence radius greater than 0 then draw a circle around it.
         *
         * @param place the place to take action on
         */
        private void drawGeofenceAroundTarget(MyPlaces place) {
            if (place.getFenceRadius() <= 0) {
                // Nothing to draw
                return;
            }
            CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions();
            circleOptions.center(place.getCoordinates());
            circleOptions.fillColor(Color.argb(0x55, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff));
            circleOptions.strokeColor(Color.argb(0xaa, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff));
            circleOptions.radius(place.getFenceRadius());
            googleMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
        }

        /**
         * Update our map's location to the place specified.
         *
         * @param place the place to take action on
         */
        private void moveToLocation(final MyPlaces place) {
            // Move the camera instantly to "place" with a zoom of 5.
            if (place.getTitle().equals("Charleston, SC")) {
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(place.getCoordinates(), place.getDefaultZoomLevel()));
            }

            // Fly to our new location and then set the correct zoom level for the given place.
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(place.getCoordinates()), new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(place.getDefaultZoomLevel()), 2000, null);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // Nothing to see here.
                }
            });
        }

        /**
         * If our place has a fence radius > 0 then add it to our monitored fences.
         *
         * @param place the place to take action on
         */
        private void addFence(MyPlaces place) {
            if (place.getFenceRadius() <= 0) {
                // Nothing to monitor
                return;
            }
            Geofence geofence = new Geofence.Builder()
                    .setCircularRegion(place.getCoordinates().latitude, place.getCoordinates().longitude, place.getFenceRadius())
                    .setRequestId(place.getTitle()) // every fence must have an ID
                    .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) // can also have DWELL
                    .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE) // how long do we care about this geofence?
                            //.setLoiteringDelay(60000) // 1 min.
                    .build();
            myFences.add(geofence);
        }

        /**
         * Connect our GoogleApiClient so we can begin monitoring our fences.
         *
         * @param fences our list of Geofences to monitor
         */
        private void monitorFences(List<Geofence> fences) {
            if (fences.isEmpty()) {
                throw new RuntimeException("No fences to monitor. Call addPlaceMarker() First.");
            }
            // PRES 2
            googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
            googleApiClient.connect();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
            /*
                TODO
                1. Display a spinner in the progress bar while we're waiting for location
                2. When connected & not null update map position to location
                3. If location null try again once every 10 seconds until we get an answer or quit after x minutes
                4. ?
             */
            Toast.makeText(this, "GoogleApiClient Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
            String lastLocationMessage;
            if (lastLocation == null) {
                lastLocationMessage = "Last Location is NULL";
                moveToLocation(home);
            } else {
                lastLocationMessage = String.format("Last Location (%1$s, %2$s)", lastLocation.getLatitude(), lastLocation.getLongitude());
                moveToLocation(new MyPlaces("Last Location", "I am here.", new LatLng(lastLocation.getLatitude(), lastLocation.getLongitude()), 0, 13, 0));
            }
            Toast.makeText(this, lastLocationMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // PRES 3
            geofencePendingIntent = getRequestPendingIntent();
            PendingResult<Status> result = LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(googleApiClient, myFences, geofencePendingIntent);
            result.setResultCallback(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "GoogleApiClient Connection Suspended", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "GoogleApiClient Connection Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResult(Status status) {
            String toastMessage;
            // PRES 4
            if (status.isSuccess()) {
                toastMessage = "Success: We Are Monitoring Our Fences";
            } else {
                toastMessage = "Error: We Are NOT Monitoring Our Fences";
            }
            Toast.makeText(this, toastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        /**
         * Returns the current PendingIntent to the caller.
         *
         * @return The PendingIntent used to create the current set of geofences
         */
        public PendingIntent getRequestPendingIntent() {
            return createRequestPendingIntent();
        }

        /**
         * Get a PendingIntent to send with the request to add Geofences. Location
         * Services issues the Intent inside this PendingIntent whenever a geofence
         * transition occurs for the current list of geofences.
         *
         * @return A PendingIntent for the IntentService that handles geofence
         * transitions.
         */
        private PendingIntent createRequestPendingIntent() {
            if (geofencePendingIntent != null) {
                return geofencePendingIntent;
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceTransitionReceiver.class);
                intent.setAction("geofence_transition_action");
                return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, R.id.geofence_transition_intent, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            }
        }


        // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // // UpdateLocationRunnable                                                              //
        // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        private Location createMockLocation(String locationProvider, double latitude, double longitude) {
            Location location = new Location(locationProvider);
            location.setLatitude(latitude);
            location.setLongitude(longitude);
            location.setAccuracy(1.0f);
            location.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
            /*
                setElapsedRealtimeNanos() was added in API 17
             */
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                location.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos());
            }
            try {
                Method locationJellyBeanFixMethod = Location.class.getMethod("makeComplete");
                if (locationJellyBeanFixMethod != null) {
                    locationJellyBeanFixMethod.invoke(location);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // There's no action to take here.  This is a fix for Jelly Bean and no reason to report a failure.
            }
            return location;
        }


        // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // // CreateMockLocation                                                                  //
        // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        class UpdateLocationRunnable extends Thread {

            private final LocationManager locMgr;
            private final LatLng latlng;
            Location mockGpsLocation;
            Location mockNetworkLocation;

            UpdateLocationRunnable(LocationManager locMgr, LatLng latlng) {
                this.locMgr = locMgr;
                this.latlng = latlng;
            }

            /**
             * Starts executing the active part of the class' code. This method is
             * called when a thread is started that has been created with a class which
             * implements {@code Runnable}.
             */
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Log.i(TAG, String.format("Setting Mock Location to: %1$s, %2$s", latlng.latitude, latlng.longitude));
                    /*
                        Location can be finicky.  Iterate over our desired location every second for
                        NUMBER_OF_LOCATION_ITERATIONS seconds to help it figure out where we want it to
                        be.
                     */
                    for (int i = 0; !isInterrupted() && i <= NUMBER_OF_LOCATION_ITERATIONS; i++) {
                        mockGpsLocation = createMockLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, latlng.latitude, latlng.longitude);
                        locMgr.setTestProviderLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, mockGpsLocation);
                        mockNetworkLocation = createMockLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, latlng.latitude, latlng.longitude);
                        locMgr.setTestProviderLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, mockNetworkLocation);
                        Thread.sleep(LOCATION_ITERATION_PAUSE_TIME);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Interrupted.");
                    // Do nothing.  We expect this to happen when location is successfully updated.
                } finally {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Done moving location.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

stack trace:

```
09-26 11:08:07.870 10417-10417/com.androidfu.example.geofences E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.androidfu.example.geofences, PID: 10417
                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.androidfu.example.geofences/com.androidfu.example.geofences.GeofenceExampleLauncher}: java.lang.SecurityException: com.androidfu.example.geofences from uid 10170 not allowed to perform MOCK_LOCATION
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3121)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3152)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2499)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: com.androidfu.example.geofences from uid 10170 not allowed to perform MOCK_LOCATION
                                                                                     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
                                                                                     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
                                                                                     at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.addTestProvider(ILocationManager.java:1096)
                                                                                     at android.location.LocationManager.addTestProvider(LocationManager.java:1298)
                                                                                     at com.androidfu.example.geofences.MapsActivity.onResume(MapsActivity.java:120)
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1258)
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6347)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3110)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3152) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2499) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have not allowed mock locations from phones developer options.
It should be under `Debug` section.

[image]

Comment: By the way I was wondering if you knew how to toast when someone walks into a geofence? I have a onHandleIntent method, and when I put the Toast line of code, it doesn't work. Do you have any insight? let me know if you want me to post the code

Comment: Sorry for my late response.
did you fixed the toast problem already?
If not, show me the code and I'll take a look.

Comment: yeah i did. It was the developer options which was not set.